# hamcrest core, why need this?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I was using JUnit for my TDD in Java and noticed there are two components to download from JUnit.org. First of all, I thought I need JUnit component and downloaded, installed. When I compiled and tried to run my test, it was complaining about Hamcrest classes are not found. So I had to download this one again from their homepage.

So, out of curiosity, why the heck would we need two downloads for one purpose usage from the beginning? Does anyone know why hamcrest core is separate from JUnit, even though it is used by JUnit?

Thanks,
Javabug

Comment: In Eclipse or Intellij, you can just add junit to the classpath. I'm not really sure what you are manually downloading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JUnit uses Hamcrest. In the past JUnit was embedding the Hamcrest classes which lead to problems, as the projects were evolving in different cycles. In recent JUnit versions (if I'm not wrong, since 4.11) this has been changed and Hamcrest is not embedded. So if you add JUnit as dependency to your project (Maven, Gradle, etc) you will implicit get a dependency to Hamcrest.

I believe this issue on Hamcrest is somehow related to that splitting. https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/92

Comment: Brilliant! This has resolved my original query nicely. Thanks, @SubOptimal!

Answer (score 3):

The class `org.junit.Assert` has a dependency on Hamcrest core library. As it is part of the static method signature `assertThat()`, it has to be on the classpath.

If you won't like to use it, a *test runtime* dependency on `hamcrest-core` should work, if you want to use it, I recommend a *test compile* dependency on `hamcrest-library` (using maven instead of gradle it's all scope *test*).

There is no transient dependency to be more flexible to upgrade [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/). Btw also [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) has a Hamcrest dependency. Read more about  [Understanding Dependencies](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extra information. It is very informative even though I was expecting the other answer.. But I voted for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you want to use as much of the "hamcrest" stuff as possible.

Have a look at [assertThat](https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/), which makes heavy use of hamcrest matcher classes.

Seriously: I am only using **assertThat** in my testy by now; and I never ever regretted doing so and abandoning all those other asserts altogether.